# how do i open a modal component by a link

Tags: vue.js

i want to open a modal from a tab link but only a fade screen shows when i click register subjects link

snippet from show.blade.php file to display selected student

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="tile p-0">
            <ul class="nav flex-column nav-tabs user-tabs">

                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-target="#registersubjects" data-toggle="modal">Register Subjects</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>

   <div class="modal fade" id="registersubjects">
      <subject-registration :studentid="{{$targetStudent->id}}"></subject-registration>
  </div>


      </div>
```

This is my SubjectRegistrations.vue component

```
   <template>
     <div id="app">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- modal header-->
        <div class="modal-header bg-success text-white">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="addPostModalLabel">Subject Registration</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
        </div>

        !-- modal body-->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="sampleTable">
                <thead>
                 </thead>

                 <tbody>
                 </tbody>

              </table>
          </div>

       </div>
    </div>

   </template>

   <script>
     export default {
     name: "subject-registrations",
     props: ['studentid'],
     data()
     {
        return {
        }
     },
     created: function(){

     },
     methods:{

    }
}
```

this my component registration  in appjs

```
   Vue.component('subject-registrations', require('./components/SubjectRegistrations.vue').default);
```

Comment: how is it related to laravel

Comment: do you have a typo in your show.blade.php: `<subject-registration` shouldn't that be  `<subject-registrations` ?